# Error using ChromeDriver when kicked off from teamcity

Tags: google-chrome, teamcity, watir, watir-webdriver

I was having trouble with firefox for my watir-webdriver tests and decided to move over to CHROME.  This runs fine local dev box, however when kicked off from team city on our qa server I get the following error:

This is using the same chromedriver as on dev box.

```
Windows 2003 Server 32 bit
Chrome 14.0.835.186
chromedriver_win32_14.0.836.0.zip    ChromeDriver server for win32
Ruby 1.8.7
watir-webdriver 0.3.4
selenium-webdriver 2.7.0
watir-page-helper  0.3.0
```

**Error**

```
[15:57:06]:  Started ChromeDriver
[15:57:06]:  port=1203
[15:57:31]:  .\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(89): error: Value of: app_launched
[15:57:31]:  Actual: 1
[15:57:31]:  Expected: AUTOMATION_SUCCESS
[15:57:31]:  Which is: 0
[15:57:31]:  Error while awaiting automation ping from browser process
[15:57:56]:  .\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(223): error: Value of: automation()->GetBrowserWindowCount(&window_count)
[15:57:56]:  Actual: false
[15:57:56]:  Expected: true
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe your problem is you're running the TeamCity agent as a service, try manually running the agent using the instructions on: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents#SettingupandRunningAdditionalBuildAgents-StartingtheBuildAgent

Comment: I tried running as not a service.  I get the identical error.  **.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(89): error: Value of: app_launched**  Though this time i actually see chrome window pop up, it doesn't actually get used and scenarios fail.

Comment: What does Firefox do when not running as a service?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using TeamCity or Watir, but I had the same error message from webdriver (using selenium server) running under a windows service.

The solution that worked for me was to run the service under another account and not the system account. Might be worth a try?